# Symfony 2 Logout

Tags: php, symfony

this is my first Symfony 2 application and i am trying to logout the currently logged in user.

This is my app/config/security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user0:  { password: user0, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
                user1:  { password: user1, roles: [ 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' ] }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        logout: ~
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic:
            realm: "Secured Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/question/*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/questiongroup/*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/answer/*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/newslettertemplate/*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/customer/*, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/statistics/*, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

I have created the logout entry in the routing.yml as described in the symfony security documentation:

```
logout:
    path:   /logout
```

When i create a link to the "logout" i do get redirected to the "/" which is ok. But the user still is authenticated, means the actual logout did not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't work with HTTP Basic Authentication because the browser remembers your credentials and sends them with each request. You can do nothing about this on the server side.

I believe eventually you're going to switch to the [form based login](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html). The logout feature will work like it's supposed to when you do.

Answer (score 5):

Just use this in security.yml

```
logout:
      path:   /logout
      invalidate_session: false
```

Answer (score 0):

If like me you are a rookie at symfony and couldnt make the others logout solutions work (i suppose i missed some config subtilities), 
there is a non academic, but functional solution:

when you use [form based login](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html) you just have to send undefined **login** and **password** to the 'login_check' route.

ex : **login**='*' **password**=''

with a button in a template :

```
<form action="{{ url('login_check') }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="_username" value="*" style="display:none;" />
    <input type="password" name="_password" style="display:none;" />
    <button type="submit">log out</button>
</form>
```

by rendering a 'logout' template from a Controller :

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load",function(){
        document.getElementById("logout_form").submit();
    });
</script>
<form action="{{ url('login_check') }}" method="post" id="logout_form">
    <input type="text" name="_username" value="*" style="display:none;" />
    <input type="password" name="_password" style="display:none;" />
</form>
```